# In Django my definiton (loop) doesn't work at other pages

Tags: python, django

I view my categories on my navbar using loop. Navbar is include in layout and layout extended in all templates. I put loop in navbar for showing categories. If I put my context to index definition It is working, but how can I show my loop at all pages? I think I need global definiton.

Mine is Django 2.1.2, Python 3.5

view.py:

```
def index(request):
    products = Product.objects.filter()
    catloops = Category.objects.filter()
    context = {
        "products":products,
        "catloops":catloops,



                }
    return render(request,"index.html", context)

def cat_nav(request):
    catloops = Category.objects.filter()
    context = {

        "catloops":catloops,
    }
    return render(render, "????", context)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.index, name="index"),
    path('about/',views.about, name="about"),
    path('products/',include("product.urls")),
    path('user/',include("user.urls")),
    path('products/',views.products, name="products"),
    path('myorders/',views.myorders, name="myorders"),
    path('dashboard/',views.dashboard, name="dashboard"),
    path('myprofile/',views.myprofile, name="myprofile"),
    path('????',views.cat_nav, name="cat_nav"),
    #user/register.. geldiğinde git user app'inden al
]
```

navbar.html:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown menu-large"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Categories <b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu megamenu">
                    <li>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6"><img src="{% static 'img/template-homepage.png' %}" alt="" class="img-fluid d-none d-lg-block"></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                          <h5>Used Products</h5>
                          <ul class="list-unstyled mb-3">
                           {% for category in catloops %}
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="/products" class="nav-link">{{category.category_name}}</a></li>

                    {% endfor %}
```

If I put my context to index definition It is working, but when I go to other pages (urls) I can't see my categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/api/) for that.

Basically, create inside your app a file called `context_processors.py`, add the following code to it:

```
def categories(request):
    catloops = Category.objects.filter()
    return {'catloops': catloops}
```

In your settings.py, add the context_processor inside the TEMPLATES list, add the file you just created:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'yourapp.context_processors.categories',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Now, in every single page, you have access to `catloops`.

You may need to restart your server.

Comment: Thank you very much! Python is amazing :)